# Load ComboBox with Json

Tags: delphi-7, pascal

I'm trying to load a combobox through a Json. I managed to make it so that when iterating in a repeating loop I add line by line in the combobox, but I would like to do something simpler. Would it be possible to give Combobox.Load(aString)? or something similar that doesn't need to loop?

I'm trying to do this to reuse the same Combobox for several different json's that will come from an api

Comment: You can assign the `ComboBox.Items` in one go if you use the `CommaText` property. Like `ComboBox1.Items.CommaText := 'One,Two,Three';` But that will not help you very much with the `json` to `CommaText` conversion.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to give Combobox.Load(aString)?

No, it is not.

> or something similar that doesn't need to loop?

Sorry, no. But, you can write a function that takes in the JSON and handles the looping.  The function can either:

- output a comma-separated `String` that you can then assign to `ComboBox.Items.CommaText`:

  ```pascal
  function ParseJSONToItems(const aJSON: string): String;
  begin
    // parse JSON, set Result as needed...
  end;
  ```

  ```pascal
  ComboBox1.Items.CommaText := ParseJSONToItems('{...}');
  ```
- output a `TStringList` that you can then `Assign()` to `ComboBox.Items`:

  ```pascal
  function ParseJSONToItems(const aJSON: string): TStringList;
  begin
    Result := TStringList.Create;
    try
      // parse JSON, fill Result as needed...
    except
      Result.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  end;
  ```

  ```pascal
  var List := ParseJSONToItems('{...}');
  try
    ComboBox1.Items.Assign(List);
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
  ```
- take in a target `TStrings` as input, and then you can pass in the `ComboBox.Items`:

  ```pascal
  procedure ParseJSONToItems(const aJSON: string; aItems: TStrings);
  begin
    // parse JSON, fill aItems as needed...
  end;
  ```

  ```pascal
  ParseJSONToItems('{...}', ComboBox1.Items);
  ```